# Класс type_info

Tags: c++, типы

Записать в файл имя функции, версию и параметр. Если с того момента исходный код функции изменился, вернуть сообщение что "версия функций не совпадают".

Например есть 100 функций. Для проверки имен и версии я думаю воспользоваться классом `typeid` (в первый раз). Поэтому из функций делаю классы.
Пример как я думаю реализовать:

```
class Base { void f(int seed) = 0; }
class C1   : public Base { void f(int seed) override; }
class C2   : public Base { void f(int seed) override; }
// ...
class C100 : public Base { void f(int seed) override; }

void saveToFile(Base *b, int seed) {
    // псевдокод. Открываю и записываю в файл
    auto t = typeid(*b);
    Fout << t.name()      // имя функции
         << t.hash_code() // версия функции
         << seed;         // параметр функции
}

void readFromFile(Base *b, int seed) {
    // тут не знаю еще как делать.
}
```

Вопросы:

1. Можно ли использовать `typeid()` для сохранения и сравнения типов классов?
2. Будет ли корректно работать, если я буду сохранять/открывать в разных версиях компиляторов С++?
3. Как красиво реализовать `readFromFile`?
4. Советы, предложения, замечания?

**UDP: ответ - нельзя использовать `typeid()`.** А как лучше сделать, что бы особо не запариваться. Что бы автоматически посчитать хеш функции/класса и сравнить имеются ли изменения. И желательно (но не обязательно) мультиплатформенность/на разных компиляторах

Comment: Нельзя. Компилятор не запоминает, что он там в прошлый раз накомпилировал, и как бы дать новый id новой версии. Стоит вынести функцию в dll, а у dll в манифесте указывается версия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По моим тестам, в Visual C++ результат вывода `type_info.hash_code()` не меняется при внесении изменений в код функций класса (он меняется только при изменении его имени). Так что идея уже сомнительная.

Хэш самого тела функции можно получить, скажем, как-то так:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <DbgHelp.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Dbghelp.lib")

struct Function {
    const char* name;   
    uint64_t addr;
    unsigned int size;
    bool success;
};

BOOL CALLBACK EnumSymProc(PSYMBOL_INFO pSymInfo, ULONG SymbolSize, PVOID context) {

    Function* pfstruct = (Function*)context; 

    if (strcmp(pSymInfo->Name, pfstruct->name) == 0) {      
        pfstruct->addr = pSymInfo->Address; 
        pfstruct->size = SymbolSize;
        pfstruct->success = true;
        return FALSE; //закончить поиск

    }
    return TRUE; //продолжить поиск
}

bool GetFuncBounds(const char* fname, uint64_t& addr, unsigned int& size) {

    bool ret;
    Function fstruct;
    fstruct.name = fname;
    fstruct.size = 0;
    fstruct.success = false;

    HANDLE hProcess = GetCurrentProcess(); //текущий процесс
    char Mask[] = "*!*"; 
    BOOL status;

    status = SymInitialize(hProcess, NULL, TRUE); //загрузка символов
    if (status == FALSE)
    {
        printf("SymInitialize failed. Error code: 0x%x\n", (UINT)GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    //поиск символов
    if (SymEnumSymbols(hProcess, 0, Mask, &EnumSymProc, (void*)&fstruct))
    {
        if (fstruct.success != false) {

            //возвращаем адрес и размер функции
            addr = fstruct.addr;
            size = fstruct.size; 
            ret = true;
        }
        else {
            printf("Symbol [%s] not found\n", fname);
            ret = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("SymEnumSymbols failed. Error code: 0x%x\n", (UINT)GetLastError());
        ret = false;
    }

    SymCleanup(hProcess);
    return ret;
}

uint32_t GetMemHash(uint64_t addr, int size) {

    uint32_t hash = 1234;
    uint32_t k = 9870;

    for (int i=0; i < size; i+=sizeof(uint32_t)) {
        uint32_t* p = (uint32_t*)((char*)addr + i);
        hash = hash * k + (*p);
    }

    hash += size;
    return hash;
}

//**********************************

void Func() {   
    printf("Hello, World!\n");  
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
    uint64_t addr = 0;
    unsigned int size = 0;
    UINT hash;  

    if (GetFuncBounds("Func", addr, size)) {
        hash = GetMemHash(addr, size);
        printf("Hash: 0x%x\n", (UINT)hash);
    }
    else {
        printf("Cannot calculate hash!\n");
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Но я не думаю, что это поможет решить задачу. Значение этого хэша в большинстве случаев будет меняться даже при простой пересборке проекта без изменений, так как компилятор каждый раз генерирует новые адреса объектов, что приводит к различиям в машинном коде.

---

Как же решить задачу? Если вам нужно отслеживать изменения в исходном коде, то и зайти логичнее со стороны исходного кода. Сделайте, чтобы тело всех функций, изменения в которых надо отслеживать, было вынесено в отдельный файл, подключаемый через include. Напишите программу, которая будет считать хэши от содержимого этих файлов, и записывать результат в XML-файл. Прикрутите ее к вашим инструментам сборки (например, в Visual Studio - Custom build step), и распространяйте получаемый XML-файл с хэшами функций вместе с программой, тогда вы всегда можете определить, какая функция изменилась. Для проверки, что XML-файл действительно соответствует текущему бинарнику, можно включить в него и хэш от бинарника.

Answer (score -1):

Насколько я понимаю `typeid()` вычисляется на этапе компиляции, поэтому:

```
auto t = typeid(*b);
```

`t` - будет всегда хранить данные о типе `Base`.

Метод `name` может возвращать разные имена при использование разных компиляторов.

Comment: `typeid()` для полиморфного типа НЕ вычисляется на этапе компиляции.