# Как сосчитать контрольную сумму участка кода?

Tags: c, crc

В моей программе есть простая функция проверки "секретного пароля".

```
int pass_check(char* A,char* pass)
{
    if (!strcmp(A, pass))
    {
        cout << "Correct" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "InCorrect" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Моя программа дизассемблируется и в ней (в ассемблерном листинге) эта функция проверки изменяется. Как можно программно в оригинальной программе(на языке высокого уровня) посчитать контрольную сумму и сверяться , были ли сделаны изменения в этой функции или нет?

Comment: А если потом изменят и функцию проверки хеша?

Comment: Вопрос академический (учебный) - как в принципе такое сделать, или вы действительно хотите так защитить свой код от модификации?

Comment: @insolor, вопрос академический, то есть он в лабораторной как часть задания. Однако мне нужен всё-таки какой-то код, который умеет такое считать

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1003049/