# Почему не запускается пример из книги Криса Касперски?

Tags: c, crc

Этот вопрос продолжение [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1053123/258486)

Этот код (на языке Си) ниже написан Крисом Касперски, он нужен для проверки и подсчёта контрольной суммы участка кода:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define PASSWD "+++"
#define MAX_LEN 1023
#define MAX_CODE_SIZE (0x10*1024)
#define OFFSET_1 0x42
#define OFFSET_2 0x67
#define x_original_1 0xc01b0574
#define x_original_2 0x44681574
#define x_original_all 0x13D4C04B
#define x_crypt 0x66
int check_user()
{
    char passwd[MAX_LEN];
    fprintf(stderr, "enter password:");
    fgets(passwd, MAX_LEN, stdin);
    return ~strcmp(passwd, PASSWD);
}
int my_func()
{
    if (check_user())
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "passwd ok\n");
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "wrong passwd\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    int a, b = 0;
#pragma pack(1)
    union anti_hack
    {
        char buf[MAX_CODE_SIZE];
        struct code_control
        {
            int local_var_1;
            int local_var_2;
            char gag_1[OFFSET_1 - sizeof(int) * 2];
            int x_val_1;
            //char gag_2[OFFSET_2 - OFFSET_1 - sizeof(int)];
            char gag_2[OFFSET_2 - OFFSET_1 - sizeof(int)];
            int x_val_2;
        };
    };
    union anti_hack ZZZ;
    // TITLE
    fprintf(stderr, "crackeme.0xh by Kris Kaspersky\n");
    // расшифровка кода
    // =======================================================================
    // копируем расшифровываемый код в буфер
    memcpy(&ZZZ, &check_user, (int)&main - (int)&check_user);
    // расшифровываем в буфере
    //for (a = 0; a < (int)&main -(int)&check_user; a++)
    for (a = 0; a < (int)&main - (int)&check_user; a++)
    {
        (*(char *)((int)&ZZZ + a)) ^= x_crypt;
    }
    // копируем обратно
    int a1 = 4;
    int *p = (int)&main;
    //memcpy(&check_user, &ZZZ, (int)&main-(int)&check_user);
    memcpy(&check_user, &ZZZ, (int)&main - (int)&check_user);
    // явная проверка изменения кода
    // =======================================================================
    //for (a = 0; a < (int)&main -(int)&check_user; a++)
    for (a = 0; a < (int)&main - (int)&check_user; a++)
    {
        b += *(int *)((int)&check_user + a);
    }
    if (b != x_original_all)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERR: invalid CRC (%x) hello, hacker\n", b);
        return 0;
    }
    // явная проверка "валидности" пользователя
    // =======================================================================
    my_func();
    // нормальное выполнение программы
    // =======================================================================
    // скрытый контроль

    ZZZ.local_var_1 = 2;
    ZZZ.local_var_2 = 2; x_original_2;
    sprintf(ZZZ.gag_1, "%d * %d = %d\n", ZZZ.local_var_1,
        ZZZ.local_var_2,
        ZZZ.local_var_1*ZZZ.local_var_2 + ((x_original_1^ZZZ.x_val_1) + (x_original_2^ZZZ.x_val_2)));
    printf("DEBUG: %x %x\n", ZZZ.x_val_1, ZZZ.x_val_2);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s", ZZZ.gag_1);

    return 0;
}
```

Можете подсказать, в чём проблема. Просто у меня ломается код на втором `memcpy`

Сама [книга](http://masters.donntu.org/2008/fvti/yegorin/library/Defence.pdf)

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что это может работать? Копирование чего-то в сегмент кода? Разумеется, это сразу упадет. В старинном DOS это еще могло бы сработать, но не более того.

Comment: Попробуйте WriteProcessMemory() вместо memcpy().

Comment: Вообще не очень понятно зачем писать в секцию кода, если для расчета контрольной суммы нужно просто читать код как данные.

Comment: @insolortiredofthisdrama там тело программы зашифровано и его надо рашифровать.

Answer (score 0):

Секция кода read-only, можно использовать функцию VirtualProtect или изменить флаги секции в самом бинарнике, например, с помощью CFF Explorer.[image]