# Почему разные функции имеют один и тот же адрес?

Tags: c++, c, ассемблер

Этот вопрос продолжение [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1053123/258486) и [вот этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1055416/258486). 
Я пытаюсь сосчитать контрольную сумму. Теперь делаю это таким образом:

```
DWORD CalcFuncCrc(PUCHAR funcBegin, PUCHAR funcEnd)
{
    DWORD crc = 0;
    for (; funcBegin < funcEnd; ++funcBegin)
    {
        crc += *funcBegin;
    }
    return crc;
}
#pragma auto_inline(off)
VOID DebugeeFunction()
{
    int calc = 0;
    calc += 2;
    calc <<= 8;
    calc -= 3;
}
#pragma auto_inline(off)
int pass_check(char* A, char* pass)
{

    if (!strcmp(A, pass))
    {
        cout << "Correct"<<endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "InCorrect"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }

}
#pragma auto_inline(off)
VOID DebuggeeFunctionEnd()
{
};
#pragma auto_inline(on);
DWORD g_origCrc = 0x2bd0;//
```

Между функциями `DebugeeFunction` и `DebuggeeFunctionEnd` у меня находится функция проверки пароля. Если с помощью бинарного патчинга кто-то изменит в .exe в функции `pass_check` что-либо , ниже указанная проверка должна провалится:

```
DWORD crc = CalcFuncCrc((PUCHAR)DebugeeFunction, (PUCHAR)DebuggeeFunctionEnd);
        if (g_origCrc != crc) 
        {
            cout<<crc;
            ishacked = 1; 
        }
```

Указал инлайны явно, чтобы компилятор не пытался с оптимизировать и создать функцию встроенной. То есть явно указываю, чтобы в ассемблерном листинге были метки и прыжки(не линейный участок кода). Для функции проверки пароля то же проделываю. 
Но проблема в том, что в Release я получаю контрольную сумму равную нулю. Более того , почему-то и адреса функций `DebugeeFunction` и `DebuggeeFunctionEnd` совпали:

```
    if (pass_check(A, pass))// вызов функции проверки пароля (в ней злоумышленник мог сделать бинарный патчинг, от этого и защищаемся с помощью CRC)
        {
            printf("address of function DebugeeFunction is :%p\n", DebugeeFunction);
            printf("address of function DebuggeeFunctionEnd is :%p\n", DebuggeeFunctionEnd);
//вывод адресов функций, между которыми лежит проверяемая pass_check
            DWORD crc = CalcFuncCrc((PUCHAR)DebugeeFunction, (PUCHAR)DebuggeeFunctionEnd);
            if (g_origCrc != crc) 
            {
                cout<<crc;
                ishacked = 1; 
            }
```

И теперь самое не понятное:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Адреса разных функций(не перегруженных) имеют одинаковые адреса. Это реально? Как это побороть?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>    // for rand() and srand()
#include <time.h>      // for time()
#include "queue.h"     // change Item typedef
#include<Windows.h>
#include <ImageHlp.h>
bool ishacked = 0;
typedef unsigned char byte;
#define MIN_PER_HR 60.0
using namespace std;
bool newcustomer(double x);   // is there a new customer?
Item customertime(long when); // set customer parameters
DWORD CalcFuncCrc(PUCHAR funcBegin, PUCHAR funcEnd)
{

    DWORD crc = 0;
    for (; funcBegin < funcEnd; ++funcBegin)
    {
        crc += *funcBegin;
    }
    return crc;
}
#pragma auto_inline(off)
VOID DebugeeFunction()
{
    int calc = 0;
    calc += 2;
    calc <<= 8;
    calc -= 3;
}
#pragma auto_inline(off)
int pass_check(char* A, char* pass)
{

    if (!strcmp(A, pass))
    {

        cout << "Correct"<<endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {

        cout << "InCorrect"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }

}
#pragma auto_inline(off)
VOID DebuggeeFunctionEnd()
{
};
#pragma auto_inline(on)
DWORD g_origCrc = 0x2bd0;//
void encrypt(char*, char*);
int main() 
{

    cout<<"Enter the password ";
    char pass[256];
    cin.getline(pass, 256, '\n');
    FILE *fp; // создаю указатель на файд, где  лежит пароль 
    fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\Elvin\\source\\repos\\Project104\\Project103\\pass.txt","r");
    char A[100];
    fscanf(fp, "%s", &A);


    if (pass_check(A, pass))
    {
        printf("address of function DebugeeFunction is :%p\n", DebugeeFunction);
        printf("address of function DebuggeeFunctionEnd is :%p\n", DebuggeeFunctionEnd);

        DWORD crc = CalcFuncCrc((PUCHAR)DebugeeFunction, (PUCHAR)DebuggeeFunctionEnd);
        if (g_origCrc != crc) 
        {
            cout<<crc;
            ishacked = 1; 
        }

        printf("Ishacked=%d", ishacked);
        Queue line;
        .......
```

Comment: Они не должны совпадать. Примитивная программа показывает это. Скорее всего вы где то в коде меняете адреса функций. Возможно в CalcFuncCrc вы делаете что то неправильно и меняете адреса функций. Попробуйте упростить программу и сделать печать адресов функций в самом начале программы.

Comment: Хотелось бы весь код программы увидеть. Тк ошибка видимо где то в другом месте.

Comment: *"Между функциями DebugeeFunction и DebuggeeFunctionEnd у меня находится функция проверки пароля."* - ничего подобного... Это они только в тексте программы так расположены.

Comment: @coder675, добавил кода, там дальше вставка в сишную очередь на указателях, я думаю она не нужна, посмотрите,пожалуйста

Comment: @coder675: Эффект прекрасно воспроизводится на практике. Никакого "меняете адреса функций" быть не может. Никакого "ошибка где то в другом месте" тут нет.

Comment: В онлайновом компиляторе адреса разные. Ниже написали что это все из за компилятора.

Comment: @coder675: Ну так само собой разумеется, что все это исключительно компиляторно- или контекстно-зависимо. На уровне языка никакого совпадения быть не должно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ни функция `DebugeeFunction`, ни функция `DebuggeeFunctionEnd` не имеют ни возвращаемого значения, ни побочных эффектов. При компиляции в конфигурации `Release` компилятор Visual Studio просто считает их одинаковыми. Он выкидывает `DebuggeeFunctionEnd`, считая ее идентичной `DebugeeFunction`.

```
  printf("address of function DebugeeFunction is :%p\n", DebugeeFunction);
00F94900  push        offset DebugeeFunction (0F948F0h)  
00F94905  push        offset string "address of function DebugeeFunc@"... (0FC04C0h)  
00F9490A  call        printf (0F948C0h)  
  printf("address of function DebuggeeFunctionEnd is :%p\n", DebuggeeFunctionEnd);
00F9490F  push        offset DebugeeFunction (0F948F0h)  
00F94914  push        offset string "address of function DebuggeeFun@"... (0FC04ECh)  
00F94919  call        printf (0F948C0h)
```

Если вы добавите в любую из функций что-нибудь с наблюдаемым поведением, например вывод чего-то в `std::cout`, то все станет работать "правильно".

В вашем примере компилятор формально имеет на это право, ибо с точки зрения языка все то, что вы делаете, включая ваши `printf` имеет неопределенное поведение.

Но вот такой код

```
if (DebugeeFunction == DebuggeeFunctionEnd)
  std::cout << "What???" << std::endl;
```

тоже считает равенство имеющим место. А вот это уже нелегальное поведение компилятора. Visual Studio, однако, считает, что оно относится к категории "вы сами попросили". Это фича компилятора Visual Studio, которая называется COMDAT folding.

Запретить такое слияние одинаковых функций можно ключом `/OPT:NOICF` линкера: `Linker -> Optimization -> Enable COMDAT Folding`. И совпадение исчезнет.

Эта возможность у линкера в свою очередь появляется только в том случае, если на этапе компиляции было включена возможность "function-level linking". Так что альтернативно в опциях компилятора можно сделать `/Gy-`: `C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Enable Function Level Linking`. И совпадение исчезнет.

Comment: теперь и вправду не ноль, и адреса разные. Я отключил aslr в проекте, чтобы в первый раз вывести эталонную контрольную сумму, а потом последующие запуски с ней сравнивать. Но даже с такой опцией crc каждый раз новое. Как это можно исправить?